# Devolver una instancia de una clase en una función anónima en PHP para hacer un enrutamiento

Tags: php

Estoy haciendo un sistema de enrutamiento mas o menos como el que utiliza Laravel pero lo estoy haciendo desde cero. El sistema de enrutado en general funciona pero sucede que necesito retornar la clase instancia para poder acceder a los metodos de la clase segun la ruta puesta en el navegador.

Este es mi folding

[image]

Este seria mi codigo

#### app/controllers/usuarioController.php

Esta es la clase de la cual quiero devolver la instancia.

```
    namespace app\controllers;

    class usuarioController {

        public function index() {
            return "index";
        }
        public function create() {
            return "create";
        }
        public function show() {
            return "show";
        }
        public function edit() {
            return "edit";
        }
        public function destroy() {
            return "destroy";
        }

    }
```

#### routes/route.php

Esta es la clase que instancio en donde coloco las rutas en el proximo codigo

```
    namespace routes;
    class route {
         function get($path, $controller, $func) {
            $array = array(
                'path' => $path, 
                'route' => $_GET['route'],
                'controller' => $controller,
            );

            if($array['path'] == $array['route']) {
                return $func($array);
            }
        }
    }
```

#### routes/web.php

aqui creo las rutas, como pueden ver, en este codigo yo recibo el `return` del codigo anterior, lo cual hasta ahora, envia un array con el siguiente contenido `Array ( [path] => usuario/1 [route] => usuario/1 [controller] => usuarioCotroller )`. Lo que quiero es que en vez de retornar ese array, yo puedo retornar la instancia de la clase que corresponde a la ruta, y desde aqui poder llamar a cualquier funcion, algo asi como `$responde->index()` donde responde sera la instancia de usuarioController porque asi se definio en la ruta

```
    use routes\route as Route; 

    Route::get("usuario/1", 'usuarioCotroller', function($response) {
        print_r($response);
    });
```

Los otros archivos que faltan no son necesarios para este problema que tengo

Answer (score 0):

Tendrías que cambiar el `return` de la clase Route, devolviendo una instancia del controlador:

```
if($array['path'] == $array['route']) {
  return $func(new $array['controller']);
}
```

Y luego podrías llamar a los métodos de ese objeto directamente en `$response`

```
Route::get("usuario/1", 'usuarioCotroller', function($response) {
  echo $response->index();
});
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu pronta respuesta amigo, pero en verdad tengo que decirte que no funciona para nada, y que por logica no tendria que funcionar ya que $array['controller'] contiene "usuarioController", es decir, una string, por lo tanto si te das cuenta, no puedes combinar el `new` con `"UsuarioController"` ya que el necesita instanciar una clase, no un string

Comment: De hecho, sí se puede crear un objeto a partir del nombre de la clase guardado en un string. Es totalmente válido!

Comment: Okey, confio en tu palabra, mas sin embargo, lo he implantado como tu me dices, pero sigue sin funcionar, me da error 500, error de servidor, es decir, hay error en el codigo, y sucede luego de colocarlo como tu me dices